# How to add a close button to the top corner of a Codename One Dialog?

Tags: java, codenameone

I've created a dialog in the designer.

What is the best way to add a close icon to the dialog (for example in the title area, top left)?

I've tried adding a command in the designer, but could not get it to work: it didn't show up.

Could I access the dialog programmatically and add a close icon?

Normally the title area is hidden so there isn't much I can do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands in `Dialog` are a bit of a special case where they act like buttons in some cases but never appear in the title since this doesn't make as much sense in a dialog.

If you are using the GUI builder the simplest workaround for something like this is to not set a title and set the layout of the `Dialog` to `BorderLayout`.

In the center area just place your UI as usual. In the north do something like this:

```
Button closeButton = new Button(...);
Container myTitle = new Container(new BorderLayout());
myTitle.setUIID("DialogTitleArea");
myTitle.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label("My Title", "DialogTitle")).
       .add(BorderLayout.EAST, closeButton);
dlg.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, myTitle);
```